# ESLint on another file extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to use ESLint on another file extensions in my project, for example *.txt. I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I read about CLI "eslint --ext .txt" everywhere, but how to insert it to my project? I can't change the suffix of my files, so I need to tell the ESLint to check another suffix.

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The eslint extension can be configured using either an `.eslintrc` file in the root directory of your project or using the `"eslint.options"` setting.

It looks like what you want, allowing specification of addition file patterns through options, is currently being worked on in the eslint project https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3611. Once this is implemented and the new version of eslint is picked up by the vscode extension it will be available for use. This will likely be the syntax by the looks of it:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "patterns": "**/*.txt",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: the moment i put `"patterns": "**/*.js"` my eslint not working on js files :( i wanted to specify all JS & MJS files..

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding an empty [override](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns).

I have an ES Module project that uses some CommonJS config files, and I found that ESLint was not picking up `myconfig.cjs` when I run `eslint .` (but it did with `eslint myconfig.cjs`). Adding an empty override to my `.eslintrc.js`* was sufficient for me:

```
overrides: [
    {
        files: ['*.cjs']
    },
]
```

* (this is a workspace where the root is not an ES Module, but the projects are)